# Different definitions for the same function space

Tags: lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

today my teacher ask me: but I do not how is possible it

What is the difference or relation between the following two spaces:

$$\{ u \in L^2 \ :\ \exists g\in L^2 \mbox{ such that }\int u\phi' = \int g\phi \mbox{ for all  }  \phi \in C_c^1 \}$$
and
$$\{ u \in L^2 \ :\  \mid \mid u \mid \mid_{L^2}  + \mid \mid u' \mid \mid_{L^2}<\infty \} ?$$

is it true? how is possible?

Comment: Since $\phi$ is compactly supported you can use integration by parts on the left-hand integral in your equation.  What would that achieve for you?

Comment: @postmortes The question of my teacher does not involucrate equation, just spaces.

Comment: Your space is defined by that equation however.

Comment: @postmortes I do not understand the relation of your answer and my question. Could you explain your point?

Comment: Your first space is defined to be all those functions $u\in L^2$ for which there is an $L^2$ function $g$ for which an equation holds.  I've suggested that you try integrating the LHS of your equation by parts, which you will find you can do because $\phi$ is compactly supported.  This will allow you to *rewrite* that defining equation in a way that will provide you insight into how the first and second spaces are related.

Comment: How do you define $u'$ for $u \in L^2$? The answer is likely implicit in this.

Answer (score 2):

In the following I'll refer to your first space as X and to the second as Y.

As the question is set in Lebesgue-Spaces $L^2$, $u'$ means the weak derivative of $u$ which is defined by $u'\in L^2$ and
$$ \int u(t)\phi'(t) dt = - \int u'(t)\phi(t)dt$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^1$.
I'll just assume, that you forgot the '-' in your equation.

So let $u$ be in X. Therefore there exists a weak derivative $u'\in L^2$. We get $||u'||_{L^2}<\infty$ and obviously already have $||u||_{L^2}<\infty$ because of $u\in L^2$. Hence $u$ is in Y.

Now let $u$ be in Y. This yields the existence of a weak derivative $u'$ of $u$ which is in $L^2$. In consequence in fulfills the equation and we get $u\in X$.

Consequently, $X=Y$ and the claim is proven.